# How many magic talents does a multiclassed level 2 spellcaster have in Spheres of Power?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, spheres-of-power

On page 8 of Spheres of Power, it states about magic talents:

> but all characters gain two bonus magic talents the first time they gain a level in a casting class

Does that mean a Shifter 1 / Elementalist 1 gains +2 talents in total or +4 talents (in addition to what each of the classes give)?

Answer (score 1):

They gain +4 talents if and only if the two casting classes Are taken as part of different traditions. In any other circumstance, you only get the two bonus talents once.

Comment: ah so if its the same tradition the two classes are taken for its just +2

Comment: citation? I'm not sure where tradition comes into this.

Answer (score 1):

This would partially be up to your DM in how he wants to interpret the below quote which I have obtained from the traditions section under multiple traditions. Emphasis mine.

> If a player or GM wishes a player to follow two traditions (similar to creating a wizard/cleric in traditional Pathfinder,) they may do so. When gaining a level in a casting class beyond their 1st, the caster may apply that casting level to a new tradition. **They gain an entirely separate set of spheres, talents, caster level, spell points, drawbacks, and boons, which are determined similarly to but completely separate from the first set.**

It states the talents are completely separate from the other class. This still would not technically be your first caster level so by RAW you would not gain the extra talents.

I see little harm in allowing the extra talents seeing as they would not share Caster Levels or be able to benefit each-other.